# Need to insert rows into df according to the difference between two rows

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I used a program to calculate pi values across a genome. However, this program will not output zero values. I need to identify windows it skipped and add the zeroes in.

Here is my file:

```
CHROM   BIN_START   BIN_END N_VARIANTS  PI
scaffold_1  1   10000   103 0.00409768
scaffold_1  10001   20000   67  0.00421737
scaffold_1  20001   30000   129 0.00856667
scaffold_1  30001   40000   142 0.00905
scaffold_1  40001   50000   188 0.0125167
scaffold_1  50001   60000   210 0.014
scaffold_1  60001   70000   158 0.0105333
scaffold_1  70001   80000   198 0.0131833
scaffold_1  80001   90000   183 0.0121833
scaffold_1  100001  110000  256 0.0170667
scaffold_1  110001  120000  263 0.0175667
```

If you see the window occurring from 90001 and 100000 is missing. Really I just need to add a line with a 0 in the PI column.

The way I thought to go about this was to add a conditional statement that if the gap between the first and second value was greater than 10,000 to add a line with the zero.  However, with larger gaps (i.e 2 or 3 bins in a row missing), I'm worried I'll end up missing them with this approach.

Comment: _However, with larger gaps (i.e 2 or 3 bins in a row missing), I'm worried I'll end up missing them with this approach._ There's a pretty easy way to find out, right? _I used a program to calculate pi values across a genome. However, this program will not output zero values._ Is it a program you wrote, or some piece of software you can't control?

Comment: How are you get the bin range in your program? if your bins are well defined in the range of 10000, the these couple of lines of code will make your data appear in proper sets
`bins = np.arange(0,df['values'], 10000);`
`df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['values'], bins)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''CHROM BIN_START BIN_END N_VARIANTS PI
scaffold_1 1 10000 103 0.00409768
scaffold_1 10001 20000 67 0.00421737
scaffold_1 20001 30000 129 0.00856667
scaffold_1 30001 40000 142 0.00905
scaffold_1 40001 50000 188 0.0125167
scaffold_1 80001 90000 183 0.0121833
scaffold_1 100001 110000 256 0.0170667
scaffold_1 110001 120000 263 0.0175667
scaffold_2 10001 20000 10 0.003
scaffold_2 30001 40000 10 0.003
'''), sep=' ')

def fill_function(group_df, step_size=10000):
    bin_start_vals = np.arange(0, group_df['BIN_START'].max() + step_size, step=step_size)
    # set our index to BIN_START so we dont lose what we have and then reindex to the full range of values
    group_df = group_df.set_index('BIN_START').reindex(bin_start_vals)
    # reset to fix up columns
    group_df = group_df.reset_index()
    # fill in empty data
    group_df['BIN_END'] = group_df['BIN_START'] + step_size

    # drop CHROM, we already have from groupby and fillna with 0
    return group_df.drop('CHROM', axis=1).fillna(0)

dfx = df.groupby(['CHROM']).apply(fill_function)
dfx.reset_index(level=0)


CHROM   BIN_START   BIN_END N_VARIANTS  PI
0   scaffold_1  1   10001   103.0   0.004098
1   scaffold_1  10001   20001   67.0    0.004217
2   scaffold_1  20001   30001   129.0   0.008567
3   scaffold_1  30001   40001   142.0   0.009050
4   scaffold_1  40001   50001   188.0   0.012517
5   scaffold_1  50001   60001   0.0 0.000000
6   scaffold_1  60001   70001   0.0 0.000000
7   scaffold_1  70001   80001   0.0 0.000000
8   scaffold_1  80001   90001   183.0   0.012183
9   scaffold_1  90001   100001  0.0 0.000000
10  scaffold_1  100001  110001  256.0   0.017067
11  scaffold_1  110001  120001  263.0   0.017567
0   scaffold_2  1   10001   0.0 0.000000
1   scaffold_2  10001   20001   10.0    0.003000
2   scaffold_2  20001   30001   0.0 0.000000
3   scaffold_2  30001   40001   10.0    0.003000
```

I think the solution can be approached by utilizing reindexing to the full range you desire. This way there's no row-by-row comparisons being done, rather you're setting up the rows you want and then populating them with what you have.

In my code shared above I removed a few more of your rows for sake of example and added a scaffold_2 to show how we would do this by scaffold rather than globally.

Assumptions:

Each Chromosome has a different range of BIN_START/END and you would want to avoid lots of trailing 0's for smaller scaffolds so you need to use a groupby

You always start at 1 for a scaffold whether the data has it or not and would want to include those with 0's.